# Wireguard does not rout all traffic over the tunnel even with 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: raspberry-pi, wireguard, upnp, kodi

I have a raspberry pi with a Wireguard Server and a number of peer's Android, Windows and another Raspberry pi. The tunnel works on all clients (for example i can ping my upnp server). The thing that does not work is that on the Raspi client it does not find the upnp server. I can ping the server but kodi for example can not find it. On the other clients it does work. VLC for example can find the server on these client's but only when i set the allowed addresses to 0.0.0.0/0. I guess that this some routing thing or the way that a upnp server works.? So i did the same thing on the pi but still it can not find the server. But ping is still working. I was wondering if this could be because i connect the pi via wifi? Maybe someone has an idea.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: UPnP uses multicast on the LAN (thus not routed). multicast over a tunnel will probably require special configuration, probably on the two endpoint nodes, to have a chance to work properly.

Comment: I'm totally with you regarding the multicast. But what makes me wonder is that on my android with VLC for example it does work. Of course only if i rout every traffic over the tunnel. and still the reason that the multicast works is i guess because the upnp server and wiregurad server are on the same device. so maybe i must change my allowed ip's on the client pi and specify the server network?